# Are text files a long string or an array of shorter strings?

Tags: arrays, string, file, text, file-io

I have always thought that text files (.txt) were always merely long strings and that different lines are created through an inclusion of (an invisible) \n.

However, although not said explicitly, I have seen references to text files are string arrays.

Are text files actually a collection of string arrays with each line being a separate string?

So, instead of a text file being:

```
String = "I went to the supermarket\nI bought a loaf of bread\nI ate the bread later that day"
```

Are text files really:

```
String[1] = "I went to the supermarket"
String[2] = "I bought a loaf of bread"
String[3] = "I ate the bread later that day"
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Text files, and files in general, are logically a contiguous sequence of bytes, or otherwise known as an Array. The operating system provides abstractions and tools so you can load parts of this array into memory on demand.

However, your application is free to load an interpret data however it sees fit, using the operating system abstractions of reading random sections of the array. If you wished to treat a text file a line at a time, making a line (delimitated by the newline character) into an individual string is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Text files, like any other file, are a sequence of bytes on a mass memory device. They are not related to data types of programming languages.

Therefore, a program can choose whatever internal data type fits best for its computations.

Answer (score 0):

Text files aren't really arrays or strings; although they can be represented that way when accessed by a program or script.  A text file is just a collection of bytes.  This is no different from binary files -- the only real difference is how the files are used by programs.

Regarding the newlines, different OSs (specifically DOS/Windows vs. UNIX) have different methods of representing a newline.  So, if you examine the content of a text file using a hex editor (i.e., Ultraedit in Hex mode), you will either see a `\n` or a `\r\n` at the end of each line.

Comment: Ah, so is this why newlines usually count as two characters in character counts? For example, in texting, because a \ is being sent and so is an n (Assuming windows formatting)

Comment: @PotWashMike not sure about texting, but true for Windows.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) has a good article on the different formats used.

Comment: I'll give it a read through, thank you.
I only mentioned texting because many of us are common with there being a constant emphasis on it being below 144 characters.